# Get the number of hours between the given dates using date-fns library

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

My api provides me with a "datePublished: "2019-11-14T14:54:00.0000000Z" timestamp. I want to subtract this from the current time, date.now() or new Date() and get the difference in hours. I am using the date-fns v2 library

From the date-fns docs

```
  var result = differenceInHours(
  new Date(2014, 6, 2, 19, 0),
  new Date(2014, 6, 2, 6, 50)
)
```

I am trying this:

```
  var result = differenceInHours(
  2019-11-14T14:54:00.0000000Z,
  new Date()
)
```

console.log(result) = NAN

When I use the datePublished value and the current date, I get NAN. Do I have to format the API date into a different format?

https://date-fns.org/v2.7.0/docs/differenceInHours

Comment: Try `new Date('2019-11-14T12:54:00.0000000Z')` instead.

Comment: That worked! thanks @Destal

Comment: `((new Date('2019-11-14T14:54:00.0000000Z') - 
  new Date())/3.6e6).toFixed(1)`

Answer (score 4):

That's because you are comparing `string` with `Date` and not `Date` with `Date`.

Check this:

```
var result = differenceInHours(
  new Date('2019-11-14T14:54:00.0000000Z'),
  new Date()
)
```